# make an array where the number that i insert gets deleted and is replaced by a 0 at end of array using pointers

Tags: c++

I'm making it in  a 3x4 matrix form

Also I'm not sure how to use a pointer since the number that I want to change and replace is an `arr[3][4]` and not the usual `arr[5]`

```
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>
int main(){
    int i;
    int j;
    int *change;
    int number; // not sure how to use the pointer to reference a [3][4] array //

    int arr[3][4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; 
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // not sure if there is a way where i dont have to write every number and just have it go from 1 to 12 //
        
        {     
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(8)<<arr[i][j] << ' '; // to make it look organized and aligned//
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }
    cout << "number" << ' ';
    cin >> number; // i woud insert the number here//
    cout << arr[3][4]; 

    return 0;
}
```

and should appear like this (say i chose 6)

```
1   2  3  4
5   7  8  9
10 11 12  0
```

Comment: `cout << arr[3][4]; ` Here, you access the array outside of its bounds. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation that you want to do is natural for single dimensional ranges, and not for multi dimensional ones. There are standard algorithms to achieve your goal with a single dimensional range.

With range views, it's fairly simply to get a single dimensional view of the elements:

```
// flat view of the array
auto flat_arr = arr | std::ranges::views::join;
// move elements to overwrite the removed elements
auto remaining = std::ranges::remove(flat_arr, number);
// fill the ramaining space with zeroes
std::ranges::fill(remaining, 0);
```

---

Without using ranges, you could achieve the same by defining a custom iterator. Alternatively, you could use a single dimensional array, and transform two dimensional indices with a bit of math. Example:

```
constexpr std::size_t rows = 3, cols = 4;
int arr[rows*cols] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

// move elements to overwrite the removed elements
auto last_it = std::remove(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), number);
// fill the ramaining space with zeroes
std::fill(last_it, std::end(arr), 0);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{     
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        std::cout
            << std::setw(8)
            // transform 2D to 1D
            << arr[i * cols + j]
            << ' '
        ;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```